# Mass Find and Replace a Variable in MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin

I'm using the following SQL query to mass find and replace in phpMyAdmin.

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

This works great when the 'unwanted_text' is a constant. But is it possible for the 'unwanted_text' to be a variable between two constants?

Here is my specific example.

I want to mass find and replace this:

```
<img src="images/stills/variable_1.jpg" />
<img src="images/stills/variable_2.jpg" />
<img src="images/stills/variable_3.jpg" />
```

with:

```
<img src="images/stills/1_constant_filename.jpg" />
```

The two constants being:

```
"images/stills/
```

and

```
.jpg" />
```

Thanks heaps for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-string-replace-function.aspx) link:

> Currently REPLACE function does not support regular expression so if
>   you need to replace a text string by a pattern you need to use MySQL
>   user defined function (UDF) from external library, check it out here
>   [MySQL UDF with Regex](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp)

On the front page of the link it says:

> This package implements regular expression functions as MySQL User
>   Defined Functions (UDFs). The functions implemented by this package
>   are:
>
> - REGEXP_LIKE(text, pattern [, mode])
> - REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, pattern [,position [,occurence [,mode]]])
> - REGEXP_INSTR?(text, pattern [,position [,occurence [,return_end [,mode]]]])
> - REGEXP_REPLACE?(text, pattern, replace [,position [,occurence [,return_end [,mode]]])

Most likely you're interested in REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: Thanks @Barney Unfortunately I don't have the programming skills to understand this but it looks like it's in the right direction. Cheers again.